# Regarding Base and Child Models: Django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have a scenario in which I want the application to fail at the compile/build time if the child model does not have `sub_field_a`.

Only models which have `sub_field_a` should be able to inherit from `Base` model otherwise the application should fail at compile/build time.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SubA(Base):
    sub_field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class SubB(Base):
    sub_field_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Here, I should get an error because `SubB`  does not have `sub_field_a`

How can I achieve this? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Django 1.7 or above, you should be able to use the system check framework; specifically, the [field, model and manager checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/checks/#field-model-and-manager-checks).

I believe it would look something like this:

```
from django.core import checks
from django.db import models


class Base(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def check(self, **kwargs):
        errors = super(Base, self).check(**kwargs)
        if not self._meta.abstract and not hasattr(self, 'sub_field_a'):
            errors.extend([
                checks.Error(
                    'missing sub_field_a',
                    hint='Add a field named sub_field_a',
                    obj=self,
                    id='myapp.E001',
                )
            ])
        return errors
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Joey. I forgot to mention this, but I am using Django 1.4

Comment: With Django 1.4 you will likely have a much more difficult time in this. One option you might have is to put logic similar to this in the __init__.py of the project. It could iterate over INSTALLED_APPS, loading the models for each and then running the above check on each of them. Other than that, I'm not sure that you could get much of a "build/compile time" trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the whole point of inheritance is to reduce and reuse common code. In this case we know sub_field_a always need to be defined. In that case why not add it to the base model like this:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    sub_field_a = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SubA(Base):
    sub_field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class SubB(Base):
    sub_field_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_field_c = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This totally invalidates the use case that is required here. Hope this helps :)

Comment: My use case requires is different and requires to throw an error